# WebApi Get method JAVA

Tags: java, asp.net-web-api

I'm tring to use a restapi in Java and keep getting error 401.

If I remove the Authorization in the webapi I don't have any problems, just when authorization is enabled and I have to pass the token in the header is the problem. I need to pass the token in the header

Here is what I have

```
public getRestTest() throws IOException{

   final List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
   providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
   WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://resturl/api/controller/", providers);

   String token = Authenticate(); //I get the Authorization token as string in here
   client.header("Token", token);   

   Response response = client.get(); //error 401 in here

   return null;
 }
```

Comment: Token is not a standard HTTP request header. Should it be a cookie? You can find standard headers like `Authorization` at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields

Comment: I'm just passing a header value with header(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object value)

Comment: I'm not sure how you get the token from `Authenticate` but the header is not correct. You shoud be using `Authorization` as @markbernard said and set as value "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE" as value

Comment: I use authentication basic with username and password in another controller called Authenticate using Post Method, that one give me the Token string that I have to use in the rest of the controllers as a header

Comment: Here's the SOAP UI Raw request for testing, I need to emulate this in Java  GET http://rest.url.com/api/GetConceptos HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Token: example-token-that-i-get
Host: rest.url.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

Comment: http://oi65.tinypic.com/3525f2f.jpg